# How does the download of Google Drive work?

Tags: ubuntu, download, google-drive, api

Recently, I downloaded some files out of Google Drive, and it seems interesting that the download bar doesn't like any other cloud service.

[image: Picture here].

The Google Drive download file is the first one. Does anybody know how? If you know, please answer the question with the API used to run the download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's nothing special, just a regular HTTP download **with no Content-Length** specified by the server (so the browser doesn't know what percentage to show). It likely uses [chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) transfer to distinguish between completed & interrupted downloads.

*(Frankly, they could have done better than that.)*

If you want to see a fancy download bar, try MEGA – [they use the JS "filesystem" API](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=mega%20javascript%20filesystem%20api), so the download progress is shown [within the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXb1Q.png) and files only appear in the browser's list once they're done.